# Django Admin: Add Hyperlink to related model

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to add a hyperlink to the related model `Training`

[image: django-admin-add-hyperlink-to-related-model]

It would be nice to have declarative solution, since I want to use
this at several places.

The "pencil" icon opens the related model in a popup window. That's not what I want. I want a plain hyperlink to the related model.

BTW, if you use "raw_id_fields", then the result is exactly what I was looking for: There is a hyperlink to the corresponding admin interface of this ForeignKey.

Comment: That's what the edit link (pencil icon) next to the dropdown is? It opens a window that edits the selected object.

Comment: @solarissmoke The "pencil" icon opens the related model in a popup window. That's not what I want. I want a plain hyperlink to the related model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update Jan 4, 2023

From [Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.1/#django-contrib-admin), this becomes a part of the official build ([related PR](https://github.com/django/django/pull/15301)).

> Related widget wrappers now have a link to object’s change form

**Result**

[image: output]

---

## Previous Answer

The class named ***`RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`*** is showing the icons on the Django Admin page and thus you need to override the same. So, create a custom class as below,

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper


class CustomRelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper):
    template_name = 'admin/widgets/custom_related_widget_wrapper.html'

    @classmethod
    def create_from_root(cls, root_widget: RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper):
        # You don't need this method of you are using the MonkeyPatch method
        set_attr_fields = [
            "widget", "rel", "admin_site", "can_add_related", "can_change_related",
            "can_delete_related", "can_view_related"
        ]
        init_args = {field: getattr(root_widget, field) for field in set_attr_fields}
        return CustomRelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(**init_args)

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        rel_opts = self.rel.model._meta
        info = (rel_opts.app_label, rel_opts.model_name)
        context['list_related_url'] = self.get_related_url(info, 'changelist')
        return context
```

See, the context variable ***`list_related_url`*** is the relative path that we need here. Now, create an HTML file to render the output,

```
#File: any_registered_appname/templates/admin/widgets/custom_related_widget_wrapper.html

{% extends "admin/widgets/related_widget_wrapper.html" %}
{% block links %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <a href="{{list_related_url}}">- Link To Related Model -</a>
{% endblock %}
```

### How to connect?

#### Method-1 : Monkey Patch

```
# admin.py

# other imports
from ..widgets import CustomRelatedFieldWidgetWrapper
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper = CustomRelatedFieldWidgetWrapper # monket patch
```

#### Method-2 : Override ModelAdmin

```
# admin.py
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    hyperlink_fields = ["related_field_1"]

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name in self.hyperlink_fields:
            formfield.widget = CustomRelatedFieldWidgetWrapper.create_from_root(
                formfield.widget
            )
        return formfield
```

#### Result

[image: Result Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much. I created a feature request at the django issue tracker: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33267 It would be nice to have this feature directly in the admin.

Comment: This is now part of the official django admin with 4.1.X, see the [PR](https://github.com/django/django/pull/15301)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go. Here is one.

Add some javascript that changes the existing link behavior. Add the following script at the end of the [overridden admin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates) `admin/widgets/related_widget_wrapper.html`. It removes the class which triggers the modal and changes the link to the object.

It will only be triggered for `id_company` field. Change to your needs.

```
{% block javascript %}
<script>
'use strict';
{
    const $ = django.jQuery;

    function changeEditButton() {
        const edit_btn = document.getElementById('change_id_company');
        const value = edit_btn.previousElementSibling.value;
        const split_link_template = edit_btn.getAttribute('data-href-template').split('?');
        edit_btn.classList.remove('related-widget-wrapper-link');
        edit_btn.setAttribute('href', split_link_template[0].replace('__fk__', value));
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        changeEditButton();
        $('body').on('change', '#id_company', function(e) {
            changeEditButton();
        });
    });
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

This code can also be modified to be triggered for all edit buttons and not only for the company edit button.